# Download a web-page with inline javascript

Tags: javascript, html, curl, inline, wget

How do I, or why can't I, get a a webpage with code such as:

```
<a href="" onclick="globals.ch.togle(this , 'E-1ibk3xv464x0x343e4');return false;" xparam="odds_text">1.38</a>
```

for instance with wget or curl?
I realize these tools have no means of following the link, but just removing the entire link from the result seems excessive. How would I go about "getting" a html file containing exactly the above line?

Comment: wget/curl don't care about javascript, they just get what the server gives them.

Comment: you'll have to implement a JS engine on your server to grab all of the code on that fetched page and execute it. wget/curl's jobs are to download bytes from a url. In **limited** cases they can modify those bytes (e.g. rewriting some urls), but wget/curl are NOT browsers and can't be expected to do everything a browser does.

Comment: thg435: Yes, but surely the server gives the client the javascript code. Otherwise I don't see how client-side scripting could ever work.
Marc B: But I don't expect them to do anything with the supplied bytes. I expect them to _not_ delete tags?
Surely, the server must return the javascript code?